# LINQ: How do I concatenate a list of integers into comma delimited string?

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate

It's probably something silly I missed, but I try to concatenate a list of integers instead of summing them with:

```
integerArray.Aggregate((accumulator, piece) => accumulator+"," + piece)
```

The compiler complained about argument error. Is there a slick way to do this without having to go through a loop?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Which version of .NET? In 4.0 you can use:

```
string.Join(",", integerArray);
```

In 3.5 I would be tempted to just use:

```
string.Join(",", Array.ConvertAll(integerArray, i => i.ToString()));
```

assuming it *is* an array. Otherwise, either *make* it an array, or use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: would it not always be best perf wise to use a StringBuilder in this case?

Comment: Oddly enough, the Join is more performant that the StringBuilder.  I did a test, and with an array 1,000,000 in size, Join took 207ms, while StringBuilder took 264ms.  I suspect this is because the Join is optimized for the task, whereas the SB is optimized more for the general case.

Comment: If I didn't have an `Array` type to begin with, is there a speed difference between `Array.ConvertAll(list.ToArray(),...)` versus `IEnumerable.Select(...).ToArray()`?

Comment: @Michael the key difference is that it might need some intermediate arrays and block-copies while it finds the length. But in most cases, you'll be fine.

Comment: The StringBuilder will probably speed up considerably if you created it with a large enough initial capacity.

Answer (score 27):

You probably want to use [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx).

```
string.Join(",", integerArray.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray());
```

If you're using .Net 4.0, you don't need to go through the hassle of reifying an array. and can just do

```
 string.Join(",", integerArray);
```

Answer (score 21):

The error you are getting is because you didn't use the override of `Aggregate` which lets you specify the seed. If you don't specify the seed, it uses the type of the collection.

```
integerArray.Aggregate("", (accumulator, piece) => accumulator + "," + piece);
```

Comment: +1 because you answered the question. However, your code has O(n^2) performance. Not cool.

Comment: @KennetBelenky, `Aggregate` is nothing but a foreach loop that sets the value of a variable. - That's O(n) not O(n^2)?

Comment: @ebb The runtime of 'accumulator + ...' is proportional to the length of the value in accumulator. The length of the accumulator string grows with each invocation. The code is performing an O(n) operation, n times. That's how it's O(n^2).

Comment: because seed is "", this would return a string with the first value a comma , e.g. ,1,2,3,4 . A solution would be to return `integerArray.First() + integerArray.Skip(1).Aggregate("", (accumulator, piece) => accumulator + "," + piece);`

Comment: the more simpler way to get rid of the extra prepended comma is ::: integerArray.Aggregate( "",(x, y) => string.Concat(x,",", y)).Substring(1)

Answer (score 5):

Just to add another alternative to @Marc's

```
var list = string.Join( ",", integerArray.Select( i => i.ToString() ).ToArray() );
```