# How do I concatenate strings in c#

Tags: c#, string, concatenation

I have a list of strings called people. I want to combine these and separate them with commas and store them in a variable called totalPeopleNames. This is what I have but it's not working:

```
string totalPeopleNames = null;

foreach(var person in people)
{
    Enumerable.Concat(totalPeopleNames, ", " + person.Person.FullName);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create comma separated strings C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884050/create-comma-separated-strings-c) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330493/join-collection-of-objects-into-comma-separated-string or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917571/linq-how-do-i-concatenate-a-list-of-integers-into-comma-delimited-string

Answer (score 9):

```
var totalPeopleNames = String.Join(", ",people.Select(p=>p.Person.FullName))
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx)

```
var names = String.Join(", ", people.Select(p => p.Person.FullName));
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
string totalPeopleNames = "";

foreach(var person in people)
{
    totalPeopleNames += totalPeopleNames + ", " + person.Person.FullName;
}
```

BETTER:

Look at C# "Text.StringBuilder":

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx
- http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Aggregate extension method:

```
var result = people.Aggregate((p1, p2) => p1.Person.FullName+ ", " + p2.Person.FullName);
```